SSRS 2019 not rendering row groups correctly
Our SSRS reports that use row groups have stopped rendering correctly in the last 2-3 weeks. We have a virtual server that has a Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard OS and SQL Server 2019 standard edition installed. The reports have existed for several years and have been running without any problems until the last couple of weeks. The reports have not been edited in well over a year. The issue seems to be related to any report using a matrix that contains child row groups that are hidden when the report is initially run. For example, the report in the screenshot below has a parent group of specialty and a child group of team. The team child group has a total row added before it and the display is set to be toggled using specialty_name.
Matrix Design
If the project is opened in Visual Studio and the report is previewed, it displays the correct specialty names and background fill for the rows and columns in the matrix:
Report Preview
However, when the report is viewed on the report server using both Chrome and Edge, it doesn't render the specialty names and background fill correctly:
Report viewed on the Report Server
As you expand and collapse the parent row group, the specialty names will sometimes change to the correct name.
Has anyone else experienced this behaviour in SSRS, and do you know how to fix it?
The only changes made on the server itself since the issues started are a couple of Windows Updates. We've tried uninstalling the updates to see if that has any impact on the report rendering in SSRS, but it hasn't made a difference.
Windows Update History
I've tried redeploying a test version of the report, but that hasn't resolved the rendering issues either. I've also tried recreating the matrix with the parent and child row groups, redeploying the report, but it still exhibits the same behaviour.
UPDATE:
With no changes to SSRS or the report, this problem resolved itself following a recent set of Windows Updates on the virtual server that was hosting SSRS.

Any custom code or assemblies shenanigans?

Nope, no custom code or assemblies in the SSRS project.

If those are unedited screen shots then the word "Team" is different ("team" vs "Team"), which suggests the version you are looking at in VS is not the same version that is deployed to the server.
